# How to make a re-usable element with $(this) triggers the clicked element only

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to make my JS logic to use the $(this) so I can re-use my code in multiple elements in the same page so that they are each triggered individually.

this is my JS code:

```
$(".fab").on("click", function(){
  $(this).toggleClass("clicked");
  $(".screen2").addClass("active");
  $(".box2 ,.box1 ,.box3").addClass("active");
});

$("#close").on("click", function(){
  $(".screen2").removeClass("active");
  $(".fab").removeClass("clicked");  
  $(".box1 ,.box2 ,.box3").removeClass("active");  
});
```

My HTML:

```
    <div class="app"> 
  <div class="header"></div>
  <div class="content">
    <h1>Click the fab</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="fab"></div>
  <div class="screen2">
    <h1>new window</h1>
    <div id="close"></div>
    <div class="box1"></div>
    <div class="box2"></div>
    <div class="box3"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

how can I use properly the $(this) ?  All I'm trying to do is to make that JS code re-usable for multiple elements in the same page so that it triggers ONLY for the element where I clicked the .fab button...

Answer (score 2):

You also need to use `$(this), .prev(), .next(), .find(), .closest()` etc. to traverse the DOM to refer to the elements near the one you're working on, otherwise it will target all of the classes in your document.

```
$(".fab").on("click", function(){
  $(this).toggleClass("clicked");
  $(this).next(".screen2").addClass("active");
  $(this).next(".screen2").find(".box2 ,.box1 ,.box3").addClass("active");
});

$("#close").on("click", function(){
  $(this).closest(".screen2").removeClass("active");
  $(this).closest(".screen2").prev(".fab").removeClass("clicked");  
  $(this).closest(".screen2").find(".box1 ,.box2 ,.box3").removeClass("active");  
});
```

Comment: isn't there a better way than using all those .next and closest? just seems so verbose...

Comment: If your elements had unique identifiers, like and ID, then yes. Otherwise you essentially have to describe to JavaScript how to find the specific elements you want.

Comment: but with a unique identifier like an ID then is not re-usable anymore in a page contains multiple instances of that HTML block...

Comment: exactly. hence the verbosity

Answer (score 0):

You can store the jQuery selectors in an array, iterate through it, and for each jQuery selector in the array, use jQuery's `.each()` to iterate through its inner elements.

In the following example, there may be multiple instances of `class1` in the DOM, for example.

```
var arrElements = [$('#id1'), $('#id2'), $('.class1')];
for (var i = 0; i < arrElements.length; i++) {
  arrElements[i].each(function() {
    $(this).on('click', function() {
      // do stuff (use $(this) to refer to the current object)
    });
  })
}
```